# I can add my Polymer app to PC desktop via a link in manifest in Chrome Dev Tools. How can I allow users to do that in the app?

Tags: web-applications, polymer, polymer-1.0, progressive-web-apps, polymer-2.x

In Android or iOS it's clear how to add a web app to home screen but I can't find how to provide a way for users to be able to add my Polymer app to their desktop as a standalone app similar to adding it to home screen on their cellphones. How can I do that and does it vary from browser to browser?

If I open dev tools in Chrome and find manifest file , I see a link that when I click on it my web app is added to Desktop. I would like to provide a way for users to do that if possible or at least guide them how to do that.

Here's the link in manifest file when opened in Dev Tools.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Currently, you can do this on desktop only if you enabled **Bypass user engagement checks** flag. But it is only for development.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I found that in Chrome it's actually as easy as going in settings>more tools>add to Desktop. Have to try other browsers but I guess you can just guid users to do that if they want to add to desktop until an easier way appears.